# Horizontal shift in tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My question is the most efficient way to do in tabular environment the last row of the table in the image below. Numbers are shifted horizontally by an half column.
thankyou!
[image]

Comment: Which image? ;-) Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that uses the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) to assure that the numeric-data columns are all equally wide. I also suggesting using the `\midrule` macro (from the `booktabs` package), instead of `\hline`, to get well-spaced horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule macro
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=-1.0}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default value: 5pt
$\begin{array}{l @{\quad} *{19}{S} }
K & 0 && 1 && 2 && 3 && 4 && 5 && 6 && 7 && 8 && 9\\
\midrule
y_K & 2 && 3 && 5 && 8 && 9 && 9 && 8 && 7 && 7 && 6\\
\midrule
\Delta y_K && 1 && 2 && 3 && 1 && 0 && -1 && -1 && 0 && -1\\
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: although this mostly looks really nice, the negative items are not centered horizontally, but look like they're shoved too much to the the left.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (complicated) version that ensures equal width of the columns and computes the differences

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,booktabs,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\difftab}{mmm}
 {% #1=variable name, #2=index name, #3=values
  \christian_diff_tab:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_christian_diff_cols_int
\tl_new:N \l_christian_diff_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l_christian_diff_data_seq
\seq_new:N \l_christian_diff_diff_seq
\dim_new:N \l__christian_diff_width_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \christian_diff_tab:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l__christian_diff_width_dim
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_christian_diff_data_seq { #3 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_christian_diff_data_seq
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl { ##1 }
    \__christian_diff_measure:
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l_christian_diff_diff_seq
  \int_set:Nn \l_christian_diff_cols_int { \seq_count:N \l_christian_diff_data_seq }
  \tl_clear:N \l_christian_diff_body_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_christian_diff_body_tl { $#2$ }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_christian_diff_cols_int }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { ##1 > 1 }
     {
      \tl_set:Nx \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl { \int_to_arabic:n { ##1 - 1 } }
      \__christian_diff_measure:
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_christian_diff_body_tl
       { && \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl }
      %% compute the differences
      \tl_set:Nx \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl
       {
        \int_to_arabic:n 
         {
          \seq_item:Nn \l_christian_diff_data_seq { ##1 }
          -
          \seq_item:Nn \l_christian_diff_data_seq { ##1 - 1 }
         }
       }
      \__christian_diff_measure:
      \seq_put_right:NV \l_christian_diff_diff_seq \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl
     }
     {
      \tl_set:Nx \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl { \int_to_arabic:n { ##1 - 1 } }
      \__christian_diff_measure:
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_christian_diff_body_tl 
       { & \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_christian_diff_body_tl { \tabularnewline\midrule $#1\sb{#2}$ & }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_christian_diff_body_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_christian_diff_data_seq { && } }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_christian_diff_body_tl { \tabularnewline\midrule $\Delta #1\sb{#2}$ && }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_christian_diff_body_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_christian_diff_diff_seq { && } }
\tl_show:N \l_christian_diff_body_tl
  %%% make the table
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin {tabular}
     {
      @{}c
      * { \int_to_arabic:n { 1 + 2 * \l_christian_diff_cols_int } }
        { >{\exp_not:N\centering$} p{ \l__christian_diff_width_dim } <{$} @{} }
     }
   }
   \toprule
   \tl_use:N \l_christian_diff_body_tl \tabularnewline
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__christian_diff_measure:
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $ \l__christian_diff_tmp_tl $ }
  \dim_compare:nT { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box > \l__christian_diff_width_dim }
   {
    \dim_set:Nn \l__christian_diff_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \christian_diff_cell:n #1
 {
  \makebox[\l__christian_diff_width_dim]{ $#1$ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\difftab{y}{k}{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6}
\]
\[
\difftab{a}{i}{0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main argument is used to compute the differences and also the number of necessary columns. Each item is added to the table, first measuring it so we can pass to `tabular` the width of the `p` columns.

Comment: in this last answer, is it possible to have 2 improvement (for my pourpuses):

Comment: @Christian What improvements?

Comment: in this last answer, is it possible to have 2 improvement (for my aims): 1) first line in italic form 2) is it possible to have a second version of the table with the second and third differences?

Comment: @Christian Yes, it would be possible; just use the same idea and from the first difference sequence compute the second difference and so on. About numbers in italics (in the first row): it's possible, but it would be wrong. *If* I find the time, I'll try it.

Comment: do you have some news for me?

Comment: @Christian How many differences?

Comment: 3 differences, please!